# Creating an SVN Repository using C#

Tags: c#, svn

I am writing some development management tools in C# and would like to hear from anyone who can recommend a good class library for creating SVN repositories using C# code. At the moment we have the windows based Visual SVN server installed but have to use the GUI to create repositories. I would like to write a C# console app which can do the job so I can create them on the fly from scripts. I have looked at SubversionSharp but it appears to only enable checkouts and commits not repository creation.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the [SharpSVN library](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/). This is what is used by AnkhSVN for example. Although I don't know if it allows to create repositories.

Update:

After thinking about it, SharpSVN is a subversion *client* library, which works *with* an existing repository. To create a repository you will probably have to call "svnadmin.exe" from your code.

Answer (score 4):

I would call the official commandline SVN tools from C#.

- Because they are called the same
  under windows and unix
- Because they are already written
- Because that way I don't have to trust any
  3rd party tool, just the official
  ones created by the SVN team.